# AngularJS Changeable Navbar

Tags: angularjs

I am unsing two bootstrap navbar classes and the default is `navbar-default` but on some pages with full width images at the top I need to change out the navbar class for `navbar-inverse`.

I have tried to set a value in $scope but the navbar is outside of my ui-view so it is not working. I am new to Angular so I don't know many of the features so there is probably a really easy way to do this.

In my page load so I need to set a default value for the navbar state? Each page controller would then set the navbar state right?

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `$scope.$Parent` to set scope properties on the scope outside the `ui-view`.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a controller for the navbar where I determine the condition.

```
<nav class="navbar" ng-class="{'navbar-default': condition, 'navbar-inverse': !condition}" ng-controller="navbarCtrl">
    ...
</nav>

<div ui-view></div>
```

Otherwise, if the condition depends on the page controller, I would inject `$rootScope` to the controllers where I can define a global variable.

```
// in your controller
$rootScope.fullWidthImage = true;
```

```
<!-- in your template -->
<nav class="navbar" ng-class="fullWidthImage ? 'navbar-inverse' : 'navbar-default'">
</nav>
```

Comment: I don't get your question!?